# How can I find the date that corresponds to a specified sum?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Let's say I have two rows of data:

```
Date    1/5/2017    1/15/2017   1/20/2017   2/15/2017   2/25/2017   3/5/2017
Received    5           10          5           5           10         10
```

How could I create a formula that tells me at which date the sum of Received equals 20? This would be 1/20/2017 in this example.

I want to retrieve the associated date listed in the top column for use or display in another location.

ANSWERED

The below 2 suggestions provide solutions to the question I proposed. The question was very general, without my specifics, and the answers didn't exactly pertain to what I needed the function to do. A new question will be asked pertaining to my exact specifics.

Comment: Do you need to return the date retrieved from the top row, or just provide an indicator in that date's column?  Also, your description points to 1/20 as the answer.  Can you explain why it's 2/15?

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake on my part. It is 1/20. I need to return the date retrieved along the top row. @fixer1234

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type this formula in B4 and fill to the right:

```
=IF(SUM($B2:B2)=20,"Quota Met","")
```

You can substitute whatever notification text you'd like.  If the number of Items Received might not add up to *exactly* 20, then you may want to use `>=20` in the SUM() portion of the formula.

[image]

**Edit 1**: OR, if you really want to see the *date* when the total items received became equal to 20, then use *THIS* formula, and fill to the right:

```
 =IF(SUM($B2:B2)=20,B1,"")
```

The same caveats as above apply.

[image]

Thanks for the compliment and upvote, @fixer1234.

**Edit 2**: If you'd like to have the answer is in a single cell without filling the equation across the columns, type this in B4 as an array formula (enter the formula with CTRL-Shift Enter).

```
=OFFSET(A1,0,MATCH(20,MMULT(N(TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B2:G2))>=COLUMN(B2:G2)),TRANSPOSE(B2:G2))))
```

For this one to work, there must be a running sum of *exactly* 20 calculated from the Items Received row.

[image]

Comment: After OP clarification, it turns out this won't satisfy the requirement.  However, it is still a simple and clever solution that could be useful to other readers.  +1

Comment: It just occurred to me that your 2nd approach could actually provide a solution to this question without using a lookup function.  In the location where the answer is needed, just concatenate all the values in your result row: =B4&C4&D4&E4&F4&G4.  Since all of the non-applicable cells contain Null, the concatenation will be the date.  It will be a text string, though, so if it will be used in date calculations, you would need to test whether Excel will handle it like a date; you might need to wrap it in a function to return a numeric value that can be used in date calculations.

Comment: If you're going to keep the row with the calculated date, this array formula finds the date and keeps it as a date, if formatted as such: `=OFFSET(A4,0,MATCH(FALSE,(B4:G4=""),0))`

Comment: This question has been kind of fun.  :-)

Comment: Marked as answer because this did not require the use of a running total row.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the answer should be 1/20/2017 not 2/15/2017 ... which means I may not understand the question.

However, what you most likely need to do is

- add a **top** row which shows, not the individual numbers in the second row, but a running total (that is, `5 15 20 25 35 45`)
- use HLOOKUP to find the value you want (`=HLOOKUP(20,B1:H2,2)`)

Comment: I revised the formatting of the example rows I gave, hopefully that clears up any confusion.
I'd like to avoid using any LOOKUP functions as I think that would just become a restatement of my question (the question I proposed is just a static example), and also because the requested formula here is a small part of a whole formula.

Comment: I will try to use the running total you advised.

Comment: @BartleyCai, it isn't clear what your objection is to a lookup function.  That's really the logical way to do what you want.  If you prefer not to insert a cumulative row at the top, you could accomplish a similar result by adding it below the Items Received row and using INDEX and MATCH to retrieve the date.

Comment: Hmm, that is right. I guess I had some bias against the lookup function. My question proposed is too general for what I need to do and I also missed a important detail; I will ask a new question with all my specifics.